# How to Identify Redis Channel Dynamically through socket in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe

I'm Trying to dynamically identify the redis channel, so to push the data through sockets based on namespace

Comment: To understand you correctly, you are trying to publish some data, and when the message recieved, checke the channel and send the data to websocket?

Comment: Yeah, Thats what i'm trying to do

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/luin/ioredis, int the Pub?sub section you can see that one of the prams in the callback function is the channel. you can subscribe multiple times and in each callback check the channel and send the message to the corresponding socket.

Comment: Hey Thanks, that was helpful